# Blazor WebAssembly application - how can I use a layout from Client project in Server project on Login.cshtml

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

As far as I know in Blazor WebAssembly applications a login form must be a part of Server project because of security reasons, that is why we have "Login.cshtml" in Server project.
I would like to use a layout from my Client project in "Login.cshtml" in Server project. Is it possible? I don't want to duplicate code.

[image]

Comment: @enet - thank you, I am learning Blazor so I will also duplicate code. :) Regarding security reasons I found: "In Blazor WebAssembly apps, authentication checks can be bypassed because all client-side code can be modified by users.". I don't know how I should understand that. It means that we shouldn't create a login form in Blazor or what?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @enet you're great, thank you :)